# Django-models - display object in Django admin by FK description

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm using the following models in Django:

**Model 1**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    GID = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    fAccountGID = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Account code')
    MainDescription = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Description/title', max_length=100)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.MainDescription
```

**Model 2**

```
class Review(models.Model):
    Code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fLocationGID = models.ForeignKey(
        'Location', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Location')
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Review for ' + self.FirstName
```

When a review is saved in my database, in Django admin it is displayed as 'Review for ' + the FirstName:

[image]

What would be the approach if I would like to display as 'Review for ' + 'MainDescription' from the `Location` model? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `__str__` and traverse the foreign key (to `Location`) to retrieve the value of `MainDescription` field:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    ...
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Review for ' + self.fLocationGID.MainDescription
```

Comment: It works and it displays as desired. However, I get an error from VSCode saying: `Instance of 'ForeignKey' has no 'MainDescription' member`.

Comment: @cdrrr This is a known issue on pylint-django: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django/issues/110 . If you were using the object name (`Location`) directly instead of string, you won't see this. It seems to be fixed in https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django/commit/f36d6e868805489d6e1dfe7bde7e3353cc115d16